# Split a paragraphs using RegularExpression (Regex).?

Tags: c#, regex

How can I split a paragraph using following methods

```
First Method =  {A-Z} <br>

Second Method =  {A-Z}<br>

Third Method =  {A-Z}.<br>

Fourth Method =  {A-Z}.\r\n
```

>

Note: Input may contain combination of all above methods.

Please help me to find out correct Regex Formula for splitting below paragraphs.

Input paragraphs:

```
{A}<br> Circulation Research. 2000;87:540-542
<br><br>
For a more detailed discussion of the mechanisms underlying the relationship between nitric oxide and telomerase activation, see this study:<br>
Farsetti.  <aomerase tale in vascular aging Journal of Applied Physiology January 2009 vol. 106 no. 1 333-337
<br><br>
{B} <br>
Chauhan. =&_orig=search&_sort=d&view=c&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=c130cff602472f25bd5680ea3047490c" target="_blank">"Aging-Associated Endothelial Dysfunction in Humans Is Reversed by L-Arginine"</a> Journal of the American College of Cardiology Volume 28, Issue 7, December 1996, Pages 1796-1804
<br><br>
{C}.<br>
Monajemi H target="_blank">Gene Expression in Atherogenesis"</a>.  <i>Thromb Haemost</i>. 2001 Jul;86(1):404-12.
<br>
{D}.
Britten M. The role of endothelial function of ischemic manifestations of coronary atherosclerosis
<br>
Kimura Y. Impaired endothelial function in hypertensive elderly patients evaluated by high..
<br><br>
{E}.<br>
9. In Cells, Aging and Human Disease, page 170, Michael Fossel writes:
<br>
In comparing young normal human aortic endothelial cells to senescent endothelial cells and endothelial cells imoortalized with hTERT, we find differences. Compared to young endothelial cells, senescent endothelial cells show a decreased production and activity of NO, changes critial in atherogenesis and hypertension. Similarly, senescent endothelial cells demonstrate increased monocyte adhesion, again implicated in atherogenesis. [..] In all cases, these differences are amerliorated or normalized by hTERT immortalization.
<br><br>
{F}.<br>
Chang E, Harley CB. Telomere length and replicative aging in human vascular tissues.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit and reformat your question? In order to accurately represent verbatim text, you need to paste it in the editor, highlight it, and then press Ctrl-K or the `{}` button. Don't try and mess around with hand-inserted `<br>` tags and the like. We need to be able to see the original text in order to construct a regex that will actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your example because the formatting is a bit off. It seems like the cases to cover are:

- optional whitespace (line breaks etc.)
- `{`
- a letter A-Z
- `}`
- an optional dot
- whitespace (line breaks etc.)

If that's true, then splitting the input by

```
\s*\{[A-Z]\}\.?\s*
```

should work.

In C#:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\s*\{[A-Z]\}\.?\s*");
```

Comment: Thanks for support.. Not able to put html tag in Editor thats why i put <'br'>

Comment: @Justin: You don't need and shouldn't add any tags; they only obscure the problem. Just paste the text as-is, highlight it and press Ctrl-K.